# Translating BitmapShader Matrix in GridView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm refactoring my custom `ImageView` to draw things using `BitmapShader`. However since I use this `ImageView` inside a `ViewGroup` which is an item of `GridView` the `Matrix` needs to be translated properly. I read that `Drawable` bounds were used for that, but couldn't open example from Google Drive and currently I am doing all drawing in `ImageView onDraw` so cannot apply that.

So how to get those translation x and y values to use that my `GridView`doesn't look like this:

[image]

Any hints are appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE:

In `onDraw` translating this way, I got better result, but when scrolling the image doesn't come along.

```
getLocationOnScreen(mViewLocationOnScreen);

mShaderMatrix.setTranslate(mViewLocationOnScreen[0],
        mViewLocationOnScreen[1]);
shader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);
```

Comment: use View.getLocationOnScreen()

Comment: Okay, that seemed to help a little bit, now when the grid is fully up, all items are drawn properly, but when I start scrolling it is not working.

Comment: it all depends what do you want it to look like when scrolled

Comment: It is supposed to be a GridView, so I want the items to scroll normally.